# When running a gradle unit test from command line, how can I get a debugger?

Tags: gradle

I'm running unit tests from the gradle command line (because running them from IntelliJ was causing problems for some reason.)

So I'd like to turn on a debug port for remote debugging from the unit test. How can I do that? Is there a way to send the `-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y` into the unit test itself? I'm using Gradle daemon mode so I'm not sure how that all works and can't find any documentation about it.

Comment: You can probably pass `-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y ` with `jvmArgs` in `test {}`. See here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html

Comment: @Opal I was about to post the same as an answer, but you were first. Why did you choose to comment?

Comment: @lu.koerfer since I can't test it right now and not sure if it works.

Comment: @lu.koerfer added correct answer, setting `jvmArgs` was not the way to go.

Comment: Please let me know if my answer was useful.

Comment: I see you found my answer somehow helpful - do you mind assigning the bounty as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually it turned out that there's no need to set the `jvmArgs` manually. Instead you just need to invoke ([docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:debugging)):

```
gradle someTestTask --debug-jvm
```

and it will stop execution and wait for debugger connection. Now when this process hangs, go to IntelliJ, Eclipse (or other IDE) and set up an remote debugging configuration (remember to set source module - red arrow):

[image: remote debug configuration]

After it's set, run the debugger and you're done. Breakpoints may be set in IntelliJ directly.

*Previous answer below:*

```
test {
   jvmArgs '-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y'
}
```

Comment: yeah looks like `--debug-jvm` was the magic answer i was looking for.